# Remove first element array Javascript Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having troubles with removing first element of a array If i try to slice(1,1) or shift I cant get a list.

For example,

my array: `[1499783769720,"54:52:00:62:46:66","54:52:00:b0:fa:57","54:52:00:8f:d9:7c","54:52:00:e7:67:10","54:52:00:26:56:56","54:52:00:33:3a:4d","54:52:00:7b:f4:ec","54:52:00:1d:48:1e","54:52:00:55:14:ed","54:52:00:78:b8:51"]`

And i want to remove the timesamp "1499783769720" and just have `["54:52:00:62:46:66","54:52:00:b0:fa:57","54:52:00:8f:d9:7c","54:52:00:e7:67:10","54:52:00:26:56:56","54:52:00:33:3a:4d","54:52:00:7b:f4:ec","54:52:00:1d:48:1e","54:52:00:55:14:ed","54:52:00:78:b8:51"]`

If i Try to slice I only obtain a single value `"54:52:00:78:b8:51"` and with sift I get `1499783769720`.

How I can do this?

```
var randomMac = require('random-mac');
var now = Date.now();
var lista=[];

lista.push(now);
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    var random = randomMac();
    lista[i+1] = random;
}
```

Comment: lista.shift(); console.log(lista);

Comment: `slice` returns the element removed. An important aspect of slice is that it does not change the array which invokes it..

Comment: Actually, "`slice` returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified" - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to understand this example:

```
var list = ["a","b","c","d"]
list = list.slice(1);
console.log(list);
```

slice function doesn't change the original array so you need to reassign the array variable.

Comment: With `list.shift()` no need to do variable reassign.. Because `shift()` method removes the first element from the  array

Comment: Yes, but mutating existing variables is discouraged in functional programming, because of the side-effects. Thus, `slice()` is preferred.

Comment: If you are looking for performance, shift is almost 10x faster than slicing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift): The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

```js
var list = [1499783769720,"54:52:00:62:46:66","54:52:00:b0:fa:57","54:52:00:8f:d9:7c","54:52:00:e7:67:10","54:52:00:26:56:56","54:52:00:33:3a:4d","54:52:00:7b:f4:ec","54:52:00:1d:48:1e","54:52:00:55:14:ed","54:52:00:78:b8:51"];

list.shift(); // First removed
console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.slice(1)`:

```js
const firstRemoved = [
  1499783769720,
  '54:52:00:62:46:66',
  '54:52:00:b0:fa:57',
  '54:52:00:8f:d9:7c',
  '54:52:00:e7:67:10',
  '54:52:00:26:56:56',
  '54:52:00:33:3a:4d',
  '54:52:00:7b:f4:ec',
  '54:52:00:1d:48:1e',
  '54:52:00:55:14:ed',
  '54:52:00:78:b8:51'
].slice(1);

console.log(firstRemoved);
```

Comment: "An important aspect of slice is that it does not change the array which invokes it."

Answer (score -1):

```
myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(myArray[0]),1);
```

Try this. plnkr: plnkr.co/edit/tFEbwbFEyVX6TarlZJ2d?p=preview 
With this approach you can pass the exact value and delete what you need exactly.

Comment: Why should this work? You should explain your answers.

Comment: I prefer to use `.slice()` because it doesn't mutate your array, but will give you a modified copy.

Comment: dont work, it gives me the first element

Comment: So, do you want to modify the array (then use `.splice(1)`) or do you want a copy of the array with the first element removed (then use `.slice(1)`)? `slice` is the better approach IMHO.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tFEbwbFEyVX6TarlZJ2d?p=preview

Comment: look at the working example.